# JQuery Accordion 1.8 Implementation

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I am trying to implement this JQuery Accordion for my site which I found here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Accordion

Their example includes 2 JavaScript downloads and a link to a CSS:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I am already using 1 jquery download (jquery-1.5.min.js) and a few other jquery plugins:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.corner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script>
```

In order to implment the same Accordion that is http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Accordion

Question1- Would I need to include the jqueryui/1.8 reference?

Question2- Would I need to implement the link to the css that is part of the example:  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Question3- I would only like to implment parts of this jquery-ui.css which would be the bare minimum CSS.  Does anyone know now could provide for a more simpler CSS for this Accordion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have jquery1.5 there is no need to include jquery1.4 but for the accordion plugin to work, yes, you need to include jquery-ui[.min].js and the css link.